# Quiero conseguir que un div se sobreponga a otro

Tags: reactjs, tailwind, slick-carousel, react-slick

Estoy construyendo una aplicación web. En el home page `/` se renderiza un componente `Home`, el cual contiene un componente `Navar` en la parte superior y un componente `Carousel` en el cuerpo.

Cuando el cliente arrastra el mouse sobre el icono "Home" del Navar, aparece un `div id="options"` de izquierda a derecha, y este debe de mostrar unas opciones, pero eso no es posible porque el componente `Carousel` se sobrepone y no me permite verlas.

Todo lo que quiero, es poder ver las opciones del `div id="options"` que se desliza de izquierda a derecha, en vez de las imágenes del Carousel.

Componente Home `/`

```javascript
import React from "react";

import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";

import Carousel from "./Carousel";

const Home = () => {

    return (

        <>

        <Navbar />

        <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-screen">

            <Carousel />

        </div>

        </>

    )}

export default Home;
```

---

Componente Carousel

```javascript
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Slider from "react-slick";

import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";

import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

export default class Carousel extends Component {

    render() {

        const settings = {
            dots: true, 
            infinite: true, 
            speed: 500, 
            autoplay: true, 
            autoplaySpeed: 2000, 
            pauseOnHover: true
            };

        const images = [
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/depcjbb7q/image/upload/v1679860246/JJ198751U-2_fmfkpo.jpg",

            "https://res.cloudinary.com/depcjbb7q/image/upload/v1679860245/JJ198751U-1_aaiq7x.jpg"
        ]

        return (

                <div className="w-80 h-72">

                    <Slider {...settings}>

                        {images.map((img, index) => (

                            <div key={img}>

                                <img src={img} alt="imagen 1" className="h-56 w-full"></img>

                            </div>

                        ))}

                    </Slider>

                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

---

Componente Navbar

```javascript
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {

    const [isHoveringTrucks, setIsHoveringTrucks] = useState(false)

    return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-around bg-red-600 h-[15%] fixed w-full">
            <div className="group w-16 flex flex-col items-center text-white text-3xl hover:text-opacity-50 cursor-default" onMouseOver={() => setIsHoveringTrucks(true)} onMouseOut={() => setIsHoveringTrucks(false)}>
                <ion-icon name="home-outline">Camiones</ion-icon>
                <div className={`options absolute bg-black top-[108px] left-0 w-full h-[420%] duration-500 ${isHoveringTrucks ? "left-0" : "left-[-100%]"}`}>

                    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-44">
                        <span className="text-lg underline font-bold">Todos</span>
                        <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(https://res.cloudinary.com/depcjbb7q/image/upload/v1686534852/Categoria_Multimarcas_xmtzaz.png)` }} className='w-52 h-28 rounded-2xl bg-cover cursor-pointer'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
)}
export default Navbar;
```

Comment: por lo que entiendo del problema, es que a nivel visual se suporpone un componente sobre otro. Si esto es asi podrias solucionarlo modificando el "z-index" en el css de las clases involucradas, dando un valor menor al que quieres dejar atras y uno mayor al que debe superponerse. Epsero sirva el comentario.
Saludos